# What is google app engine sdk directory in windows?

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

[image]

I am trying to setup app engine with Pycharm. But Pycharm is unable to detect Google app engine SDK directory.

What is wrong here? Please help.

Comment: Which SDK did you install? The Cloud SDK or the original App Engine SDK?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Looks like you installed the Cloud SDK. So I think you need to know/do two things:

1. Prior to configuring Pycharm, you'll need to get the Python App Engine component for the Cloud SDK. For most users, you'll be prompted for this as soon as you run `gcloud app deploy` or start the local development server (`dev_appserver.py`), but you wouldn't have run those yet, so do the following:

   ```
   gcloud components install app-engine-python
   ```
2. After installing the component, you will now have the Python portion of the SDK, which is installed by default at the following path:

   ```
   C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\
   ```

   Or on Mac:

   ```
    /Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengin‌​e
   ```

   Add this as your App Engine SDK path to PyCharm.

Comment: On mac it should be /Users/roneythomas/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine

Comment: Updated answer with the extra bit for mac users. Thanks.

Comment: Default path on windows is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine`

Answer (score 6):

If you install google cloud SDK **for current user** the above answers are valid, googe_appengine path is

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\
```

If you install google cloud SDK **for all users** the google_appengine path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
```

Comment: Yes - the AppData directory was missing for us because we installed for all users.

Comment: We discovered the AppData directory is hidden. By clicking an icon that says "show hidden" in the popup file browser in PyCharm then we were able to find and navigate that directory.

Comment: These paths are not working for us. Strangely after installing the Google SDK both for a single user and for all users - we still cannot get PyCharm to recognize that there is an interpreter. Additionally, the google_appengine directory mentioned above doesn't exist even though we have navigated to the user's directory we just used to install it.

Comment: This worked for us: we had to use a different directory for **all users** - notice it needs the google-appengine folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine

Answer (score 6):

In Linux (Ubuntu), If you had installed Google-Cloud-SDK via apt-get than default installation directory for App engine SDK is

```
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
```

Note: App Engine doesn't support if your python interpreter version is greater than 2.x (< Python 3.x).